# How is default page-file size actually calculated by Windows?

Tags: windows, memory, pagefile

I want to know how does Windows calculate default page file size. For example, for 48 GB RAM it shows 7168 MB page file size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How does Windows calculate default page file size?

There is no exact formula for this, because:

> Page file sizing depends on the system crash dump setting requirements and the peak usage or expected peak usage of the system commit charge. Both considerations are unique to each system, even for systems that are identical. This means that page file sizing is also unique to each system and cannot be generalized.

...

> **System-managed page files**
>
> By default, page files are system-managed. This means that the page
> files increase and decrease based on many factors, such as the amount
> of physical memory installed, the process of accommodating the system
> commit charge, and the process of accommodating a system crash dump.

The system may change to page file size on the fly:

> when the system commit charge is more than 90 percent of the system
> commit limit, the page file is increased to back it. This continues to
> occur until the page file reaches three times the size of physical
> memory or 4 GB, whichever is larger. This all assumes that the logical
> disk that is hosting the page file is large enough to accommodate the
> growth.

If you let the OS manage the page files then read on for how to calculate minimum and maximum page file size:

> **Minimum page file size**
>
> Varies based on page file usage history, amount of RAM (RAM ÷ 8, max
> 32 GB) and crash dump settings.
>
> **Maximum page file size**
>
> 3 × RAM or 4 GB, whichever is larger. This is then limited to the
> volume size ÷ 8. However, it can grow to within 1 GB of free space on
> the volume if required for crash dump settings.

Source [How to determine the appropriate page file size for 64-bit versions of Windows - Windows Client Management | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/determine-appropriate-page-file-size)